# Nested attributes not working creating children with new parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have two models:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ranges_attributes
  has_many :ranges
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ranges, allow_destroy: true
end

class Range < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shift
  validates :shift, presence: true
end
```

When, in my controller, I want to create a shift with ranges I'm getting:

```
Shift.create! params[:shift]
#ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Shift ranges shift can't be blank
```

If I remove `validates :shift, presence: true` from `Range` model this works beautifully. I'm able to create a new shift with his children. `ActiveRecord` does that for me.

The question is: **why do I need to remove that validation to make this work?**

Comment: You should provide that is children model for dependent destroy..

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that the new `Shift` and `Range` objects are created during one transaction. It might be that `Shift` does not really exists at the moment you try to create the new `Range` and this might cause the validation error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing with validating presence of parent like this is **timing** !! actually the `Shift` is not yet saved so when trying to create nested `ranges` it won't find parent `Shift` in database.

I found this workaround [**here**](http://railsguides.net/2013/07/13/belongs-to-association-and-validate-presence-with-nested-attributes/)

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ranges_attributes
  has_many :ranges, :inverse_of => :shift
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ranges, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and i quote (with minor modifications) from the same source:

> With this option rails won't try to get parent from database when
>   child is validated. The parent will be got from memory. If you don't
>   familiar with this option I strongly recommend you to read an official
>   [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-inverse-of)