# Nested forms in Rails 4 using Cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I am trying to create nested forms using Cocoon gem.
I use documentation provided at github.
I have set a models like that:

```html
//requst.rb
has_many :filled_cartridges, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :filled_cartridges, :reject_if => :all_blank,
                                                  allow_destroy: true

//filled_cartridge.rb
belongs_to :request
```

In my _form i have nested form:

```html
<%= f.fields_for :filled_cartridges do |filled_cartridge| %>
 <%= render 'filled_cartridge_fields', f: filled_cartridge %>  
 <%= link_to_add_association 'add', f, :filled_cartridges %>
<% end %>
```

and my _filled_cartridge_fields partial:

```html
<fieldset>
  <%= f.text_field :cartridge_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
</fieldset>
```

Also i have defined strong params for :id and :_destroy inside request_controller.

link_to_add_association isn working, remove works fine.
I have no idea why is  it like that. Also when I click on link_to_add_association default action is done, i.e navigation to /# page.

Comment: when you click on add button is the partial rendered? the problem is you can persist the new item on db, right?

Comment: @Leantraxx no partial is not rendered

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is related with this:
[Nested attributes not working creating children with new parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991443/nested-attributes-not-working-creating-children-with-new-parent)

you need to add `inverse_of` attribute in order to make it work

```
has_many :filled_cartridges, inverse_of: :request, dependent: :destroy
```